# Перенаправление поддоменов с использованием proxy pass

Tags: nginx, proxypass

Всем привет! Не могу разобраться, как правильно настроить работу динамических поддоменов с Nginx.

Представим, что у меня есть огромное кол-во поддоменов, заранее не известны их названия. Фронт работает на Next.js (например на порту 3000). Все запросы, которые поступают на адрес типа `abc.domain.com/test` необходимо направлять на `domain.com/abc/test`. В этом примере `abc` это slug, который является именем поддомена, `test` это путь, который необходимо обработать. Вот еще некоторые примеры: `abc1.domain.com/a/b/c` --> `domain.com/abc1/a/b/c`, `abc2.domain.com` --> `domain.com/abc2` и так далее. Пользователь не должен видеть прямой путь, должен постоянно находиться на поддомене.

Пробовал вот так:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name ~^(.*)\.domain\.com$;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:3000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Но это работает только для прямых запросов `abc.domain.com/` -- открывает `domain.com/`

Буду рад любым комментариям!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно из поддомена получить первый сегмент, а затем реврайтить на нужный URL.

```
http {
  # Мапим поддомен и префикс
  map $host $prefix {
    "~^([^.]+)\.domain\.com" /$1;
  }

  server {

    # Добавляем префикс к URL
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $prefix$1 last;

    location / {
      proxy_pass ... ;
    }
  }
}
```